# Is there a free UNIX shell service that allows you to test function keys?

Tags: command-line, unix, keyboard, shell, function-keys

I am testing a program that is a terminal emulator that runs through a web browser. I'd like to use a free UNIX shell service to test the function key maps (this program can also generate a function key map or you can manually put one in). I ask this because someone wants to be able to use the arrow keys and things of that nature.

Answer (score 1):

I think you will struggle to find a service that gives you gratis access to a terminal on any server on the Internet unless you have friends that host these kinds of services.

You can try to use virtual hosts for your problem, meaning that you install a hypervisor on your machine, then install the operating system you want using that hypervisor and test your software that way.

There are several hypervisors that can be used and that are as far as I know gratis to use.

- [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org)
- [QEMU](http://wiki.qemu.org/Main_Page)
- [VMware vSphere](https://www.vmware.com)
- [XEN](http://www.xenproject.org/)

Comment: I'm finding the search for a free UNIX account to be a bit on the useless side. Alot of them don't care for free accounts and the free accounts are limited. They also want more information than I care to give which I suspect is because, as I've read, alot of hackers use UNIX shells in the past to be damage.

Comment: I know AIX is a popular system. Can one download AIX and use any of those things for that?

Comment: If you think about it, if the service is free, how are they making money? Probably by selling your details to some bid number crunching company. If you want things to be free, you have to expect having to give something else up.